# Can't download file using HTML5 download attribute

Tags: html, download, anchor, google-docs

I'm trying to create a download link the way it always worked for me. But now it keeps redirecting me to Google Docs – I've never experienced that before, this should be a straight-forward task to do, so it quite shocked me.

I use the HTML5 download attribute:

```
<a href="../files/uploads/myfile.docx" download>myfile.docx</a>
```

But I always end up redirected to Google Docs. I also opened the Chrome dev console and noticed that after I click on the link, it changes the href to Google Docs. I have no clue why.

The path should be alright, I can't figure out the problem. What shall I do?

Comment: Sounds like you have a browser extension that hijacks links to Word documents.

Comment: @Quentin Thank God for your comment. I was getting mad about it. Don't remember installing this extension, but… it was there.

Answer (score 0):

The download attribute only works for same-originl URLs. So if the href is not the same origin as the site, it won't work. In other words, you can only download files that belongs to that website. This attribute follows the same rules outline in the same-origin policy

Comment: I have a directory containg the files in root. Then another directory also in root, that contains the HTML with download link. So the files have the same root as the HTML, so this shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).